# extract some values from file#1 and others from file#2 and print them into file#3

Tags: sed

I hope you can help with this question, I have two files, each one has some lines that I need in a third file. But I need to take some entire lines (with values in 5 or 6 columns) from file#1 and others from file#2 and save them in file#3 (keeping the line number). Example:

**File 1**

```
 1. mike
 2. linda
 3. matt
 4. eric
 5. emma
```

**File 2**

```
 1. beth
 2. shelly
 3. michael
 4. andy
 5. theo
```

**File 3 (output)**

```
 1. mike
 2. shelly
 3. matt
 4. andy
 5. emma
```

So, I need to extract the values of line 2 and 4 (from file#2) and print them in a third file while keeping the content of lines 1, 3 and 5 from file#1.

I tried this using sed (easy example):

```
sed -n -e 1,3p -e 5p file1.txt > file3.txt
```

This will take lines 1,3 and 5 from my file#1 and print them in file#3, but I don't know how to get the lines from file#2 (2 and 4) and add them into file#3.

[image]

Comment: which of these requirements are real? do you really have 5 lines in each file? Are these the only lines you are interested in?

Comment: actually not, its a simplification, since my real file has 4015 lines and like 6-7 columns (numbers not names), so I used this just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep to annotate with file names:

```
grep -H '.*' in1 in2 | sed '/in1:[24]/d;/in2:[135]/d;s/[^:]*://' | sort
```

Output:

```
1. mike
2. shelly
3. matt
4. andy
5. emma
```

Comment: The repetition operator `*` isn't really necessary here. You could just `grep ^` to get every line including empty lines.

Comment: Hi again. May I ask how can I separate the line-numbers from each other? [24] and [135]. And what would be the function of 'sort'? Because its mixing up the lines in the output file. I know the 'real case' is more complicated since it has thousand lines, but I'm trying to find the way with a sample-file of 18 lines, later on I can add the total line-numbers. I'll have to repeat this operation few times, so I thought that it was better to have a sort of script to do it. I'd appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`sed` probably isn't a very suitable tool for this.  How about

```
paste in1 in2 | awk -F '\t' '{ print $(1+(1+NR)%2) }'
```

The Awk variable `NR` is the current input line number and the modulo operator `NR%2` flip-flops between 1 and 0. We need to perform a couple of additions to get it to flip-flop between 1 and 2. Then it's easy to print alternating columns from the `paste` output.